# Problem with automatic calculation in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

In Excel Sheet1 I have a complicated calculator with multi-step calculations. In practice, it looks like this: in cell A1 you insert a number and in cell C10 you display the result of the calculation (let's assume that this is the profit from some investment). Of course, the formula is not so simple that it can be pasted into the formula bar and simply "dragged" to other cells.

The problem is as follows:
In Sheet2 in the same workbook I have a table with values and I would like the "result" field to display the results of the calculations from Sheet1 (exactly as if I would enter the numbers 500, 501, etc. there one by one and rewrite them to after the calculations are done).
How to do this in the easiest way? Some recursive function or something like that?

[image: screenshot]

How to do this in the easiest way? Some recursive function or something like that?

Comment: Without sharing what type of formula you're using, we can't help you further. It may be real easy just locking the ranges with $ except the cell reference to the value

Answer (score -1):

[Goal Seek](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/use-goal-seek-to-find-the-result-you-want-by-adjusting-an-input-value-320cb99e-f4a4-417f-b1c3-4f369d6e66c7?ns=excel&version=90&syslcid=1033&uilcid=1033&appver=zxl900&helpid=20922&ui=en-us&rs=en-us&ad=us)  feature can help you. With it, you will not have the table, but you can find a solution in the defined range of input values.

Another way is to program your calculations by a user-defined function. You can fill out 'result' cells with this function referred 'value' cells.

But I guess [Data Table](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/calculate-multiple-results-by-using-a-data-table-e95e2487-6ca6-4413-ad12-77542a5ea50b?ns=excel&version=90&syslcid=1033&uilcid=1033&appver=zxl900&helpid=20917&ui=en-us&rs=en-us&ad=us) feature (Data/What-If Analysis) is that what you need.

[image]

For this sample, select `A2:B11` and apply `Data --> What-If Analysis --> Data Table`. Refer to `D3` and `D4`. Put the final formula in `A2` (your formula in `C10`). Refer `D4` as the input value (your `A1`).

Comment: How is it going?